# What is the purpose of the "C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations\" folder?

Tags: windows

I see this folder under Windows 7 x64 and also Windows 8 x64. What is its purpose?

Comment: Its not a system folder, it probably softwares, drivers downloaded by somebody, or the OEM

Answer (score 8):

That folder seems to be a deposit for uninstallation resources and executables. you can remove the contents if you need extra space but you will cripple any software needing repair and/or uninstallation.

[source](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/c-windows-downloaded-installations-t2378268.html)