# What would be the harm of moving the "Downloaded Installations" folder to my second hard drive?

Tags: windows, storage

I seem to have an outrageous amount saved to the "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Downloaded Installations" folder on my personal computer that has no obvious use to me. [This](https://superuser.com/a/533290/1332817) Super User discussion warns against deleting the folder. However, the "C" drive is my fast but small solid-state drive. I have a second hard drive in this computer, the "D" drive, that has a huge amount of space available (though it is a slower drive, as it is not solid-state).

What would be the harm of moving that folder to the "D" drive? What about if I keep the folder there but move the contents to the "D" drive?

Comment: How about just moving the contents of the folder to D:? You may need to move individual program's files back to uninstall or modify them. (I can't say this will definitely work.)

Comment: Normally better to move the contents but File Explorer allows you to move the folder. Just remember to keep track

Comment: @John What would be the harm of doing such a move?

Comment: No harm. I just like to keep Windows on Drive C: for my own clarity and extra files to a folder on the other drive.

Comment: Use directory symbolic links or junctions.  Copy this folder (from drive a) to the other drive anywhere you want it.  Rename the folder ***on drive a*** to ANYTHING else.  Create a junction or directory symbolic link from drive b to original location on drive a.   After verifying everything is ok, delete renamed folder from drive a.  Programs won't know the difference (to include windows itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked in both folders on my computer :

- `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Downloaded Installations`
- `C:\Windows\Downloaded Installations`

Both contain very few and small installations of products that I have
installed quite some time ago.

My opinion is that these are temporary storage areas for installations
and have no importance.

To be safe, I would suggest moving these files to another disk as backup
(or at least the biggest sub-folders),
waiting a few weeks and then deleting them.